# InvalidArgumentException: Database [database] not configured

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku, laravel-5.3

I have deployed a web app to heroku and everything seemed to be okay. I ran the migration and it was successful.

When I try to open the app in a browser am getting the below error, what could be the problem? Having in mind the migration was successful and when I access the heroku DB from my localhost it is working well.

```
production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Database [database] 
not configured. in /app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:11774
```

Kindly help.

Comment: have you configured environment variable which we define in .env for local? in heroku you have to configure those env variables in the settings section of your application. add all variable which are defined in .env file and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Sam, 
I tried that but same error persists. Will try to do it from scratch again.

Comment: try to clear your Configuration and reload the page `php artisan config:clear`